# Facebook Connect (C# SDK) - How to See if User is Authenticated to FB, But Don't Force?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, single-sign-on

I'm implementing a single sign on between Facebook Connect and my ASP.NET MVC 3 website, using the Facebook C# SDK.

Now, part of the single sign on is:

> If the user is authenticated to Facebook, but not to my website, see if they are connected in my system and if so, perform a single sign on (using Forms Auth).

Now, i don't know how to "see if the user is authenticated". I'm using OAuth for server-side authentication, so i don't want to force them to sign in via the login page, just a silent check. If they're not authenticated, i wont do anything - i'll just wait for them to click the "Connect with Facebook" button.

We can do this with the JavaScript API - can we do it server-side?

I basically want the equivalent of **[FB.getLoginStatus](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/)** via the Graph API.

Surely there must be a way server-side - at least if not via the Graph API, the old REST api or FQL?

Comment: This is kinda hackish, but you could record the JS API request and forge it using `HttpWebRequest`.

Comment: @PizZL3 - you can't, as you'd need to include the JS library in the project, which is what i'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @Nathan Totten - if you are out there i would really appreciate your advice/thoughts on this issue - as without it, a single sign on is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of hunting around the net, including the Graph API, old REST API, FQL, etc - it seems the JavaScript SDK is the only one that allows this information without having a access token beforehand.

So, i had to use the JavaScript SDK:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({ appId: 'xxxxxxx', status: true, cookie: false, xfbml: false
        });
        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            if (response.session)
                window.location = '/Facebook/LogOn'
        });
    };
    (function () {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    } ());
</script>
```

Basically, i first load the JS API aysynchonrously to avoid blocking.

I then see if the user has a Facebook session. If they do, i redirect to my `FacebookController`, which does the OAuth redirect (which will come back straight away with the token - since they're already auth'ed), with then sets my own cookie.

My global action filter then kicks in, sees there is a cookie, and logs the user in. Nice.

Note how i have `cookie: false` - this is because i'm tracking my own cookies for the OAuth token and FB ID.

Comment: Can you share what method to use if you DO have a token beforehand? I can't seem to fund the appropriate documentation. Thanks

Comment: @Basiclife - well when they first authenticate to FB (via OAuth), i store the access token in a cookie (expiry with the expiry for the token). I then set this in the ViewBag on every page, if i need to access it. As for seeing if they have a *facebook* session, i use `FB.getLoginStatus`, as above. This runs on every page load. But before i redirect to Facebook, i make sure the user is NOT authenticated to my website. There's a bunch of different scenarios, but that's basically it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I was hoping to find a server-side solution but it seems it relies on iframes to see if a user has a cookie - which I can't replicate.

Comment: @Basiclife - your preaching to the converted. :) Your exactly right, the reason there is no Graph API method for this, is that the fb session is exposed via the cross domain iframe and cookies. There is no way to do this server-side.

Comment: @RPM1984, I know this question is almost 3 years old... But I am dealing with the exact same thing right now. OK, so you used the Javascript SDK... but where? Where and when do you call the SDK API?

Answer (score 0):

You can (ab)use the HTTP status codes to find that information about Facebook, the technique is described here

https://grepular.com/Abusing_HTTP_Status_Codes_to_Expose_Private_Information

Comment: Thanks for the alternative - but that's a bit too dodgy IMO. Last resort is of course the JavaScript SDK. I'm hoping there is a Graph API call i can use - or at least the old REST API.