# When is Facebook deprecating the JavaScript SDK?

Tags: facebook, deprecated, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-authentication

I've asked this on the Facebook Developer Forums, but no-one is answering, so thought i'd ask it on Stack.

I've got a website which integrates with Facebook Connect using OAuth for authentication. But i have some code which leverages the [JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/).

I have heard that the JavaScript SDK is being deprecated and/or authentication via the JavaScript SDK is being deprecated.

Can anyone:

- Confirm if the above statement is true
- Provide a link giving the date that it is to be deprecated
- Tell me im wrong

**EDIT**

For anyone who is curious as to why i still use the JavaScript SDK, see [my other Stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508057/facebook-connect-c-sdk-how-to-see-if-user-is-authenticated-to-fb-but-dont) for the reasoning.

In short, this cannot be done with OAuth/Graph API:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
   if (response.status == 'connected') {
      // do single sign on, seamlessly.
   }
}
```

Comment: if your going to vote to close as off topic, at least give a reason. i realise the developer forums are more appropriate, but as i said, getting no love. what else can i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be very clear, we are not deprecating the [JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/). It's here to stay. We are in the process of changing it to rely on [OAuth 2.0](http://tools.ietf.org/pdf/draft-ietf-oauth-v2.pdf), but it will be just as simple to use. If you use `access_token` today, then the changes will be minor (largely replace `session.access_token` with `authResponse.accessToken` once the updated JS SDK is out). If you rely on `session_key` and `secret` and use md5 signature based calls, then you have some migrating to do since those will go away in the OAuth 2.0 only world.

Comment: "We"? So are you on the Facebook team? And so are you saying we can continue to use "FB.getLoginStatus", xd_receiver.htm, etc

Comment: I'm an engineer in the the Platform team at Facebook, by "we" I meant Facebook -- should have been clearer about that. You can indeed keep using `FB.getLoginStatus`, keeping in mind the changes wrt to OAuth 2.0 as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

**Migration to OAuth 2.0 + HTTPS timeline:**

- July 1: Updates to the PHP and JS SDKs available that use OAuth 2.0 and have new cookie format (without access token).
- September 1: All apps must migrate to OAuth 2.0 and expect an encrypted access token.
- October 1: All Canvas apps must process signed_request (fb_sig will be removed) and obtain an SSL certificate (unless you are in Sandbox mode). This will ensure that users browsing Facebook over HTTPS will have a great experience over a secure connection.

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/497
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/connect_auth/

Comment: but is this deprecating the javascript sdk *altogether*, or just the javascript sdk for *authentication*. as usual, the fb doco isnt really clear. im not using it to authenticate, but im using `FB.init` and some other methods.

Comment: I don't see them deprecating the entire JavaScript SDK, just changing the authentication parts as they had some security issues.

Answer (score 0):

The older SDK is already deprecated but will be available for you to use. [But you should really think about migrating to the new SDK](http://alekseykorzun.com/post/6919673137/why-are-you-still-using-facebooks-legacy-javascript-sdk).

Currently the latest PHP-SDK is out of sync in terms of authentication implementations with JS; they will be rolling out few changes to both of the SDK's in the near future to unify some of the routines.

Comment: trust me, i would love to move to the API. Here's why i can't: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508057/facebook-connect-c-sdk-how-to-see-if-user-is-authenticated-to-fb-but-dont

Comment: @Sean that time line is behind the schedule ATM.

Comment: @RPM I don't use ASP but if you are having problems transfering session from Social Plug-ins to PHP-SDK (v3.0) I have a patch for that here: http://alekseykorzun.com/post/6925234287/integrating-facebooks-social-plug-ins-with-facebook-php

Comment: @RPM1984 This might be what your looking for http://amirrajan.net/Blog/asp-mvc-and-facebook-single-sign-on

Comment: @Sean - yep, i can do all that. but the trick is, that requires the user to explicitly click the "Connect with Facebook" button. With the JavaScript API, you can "detect" if they're already logged in, and do the sign in automatically. this is because the JavaScript API allows my site access to Facebook's cookies, which the Graph API does not. Hence my conundrum.

Answer (score 0):

The current javascript SDK definitely isn't being deprecated.  Perhaps they will deprecate the old Facebook connect javascript, but they haven't announced a date.  The best place for deprecation dates is the [Facebook developer roadmap.](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/)